# Why was this question voted to be migrated to Worldbuilding Meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We recently got the question [Proof of our existence](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10641/29) on the main site. It's now closed, hopefully pending edits to fix it up and perhaps migrate it to a more suitable site, but there's something I saw which made me really curious.

**The question was voted to be migrated *here*, to Worldbuilding Meta.**

The meta site is supposed to be *about our* site.

If someone involved would be willing to step up (I see no reason to name any name(s)), I would be really interested in learning more about why it was flagged as a potential candidate to migrate to Meta.

Comment: I was not sure what to do about it. Personally, I would have it migrated probably to Philosophy SE. Someone proposed to move it here instead and I thought it was ok. We discuss about off topic questions from time to time, no?

Comment: But I realize it was not the best thing to do.

Comment: How many migration votes were there?

Comment: When I originally flagged it, the only option I was given for migration was Worldbuilding Meta (where it obviously did not belong), so I backed up through the option tree and chose...some other option that I don't remember at the time. It's possible whoever else voted for migration only had Worldbuilding Meta as an option. Or, that my original vote got committed for migration to Worldbuilding Meta.